# AKS cluster Link load balancer with existing services

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

i moved a group of containers was running on Docker compose, into AKS, all working well and can interact each other and internal resources, now i wanted to allow access from internet to two of pods, i tried to install a load balancer in AKS right now when i run kubectl get services

```
    NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)               AGE
foo                   ClusterIP      10.0.9.29      <none>           61616/TCP,8161/TCP    10d
bar                 LoadBalancer   10.0.36.29     xxxxxxxxxxxx        80:30746/TCP          93m
fooffoo             ClusterIP        10.0.149.241   <none>           50443/TCP,50080/TCP   2d21h
fooofooo              ClusterIP      10.0.213.154   <none>           51443/TCP,51080/TCP   10d
foo123                ClusterIP      10.0.205.194   <none>           9200/TCP              10d
kfoo1                 ClusterIP      10.0.62.38     <none>           8080/TCP              10d
kfoo12                ClusterIP      10.0.79.100    <none>           5601/TCP              10d
kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>           443/TCP               10d
public-svc            LoadBalancer   10.0.107.55    xxxxxxxxxxx    80:32152/TCP
```

I tried to assign the load balancer to service using the following in service yaml:

```
status:
  loadBalancer: public-svc
~
```

But i got error when i apply, how can i correctly get those services linked to the load balancer
So > load balancer > service service > pod

Comment: please share the manifest of your `Service`.

Comment: ```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: ./kompose convert -f docker-compose.linux
    kompose.version: 1.28.0 (c4137012e)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "9200"
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: elasticsearch
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Then tried this:
```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: ./kompose convert -f docker-compose.linux
    kompose.version: 1.28.0 (c4137012e)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "9200"
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: elasticsearch
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using the following service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service 
metadata: 
  name: elasticexternal
spec: 
  type: LoadBalancer 
  ports: 
  - port: 9200 
  selector: 
    io.kompose.service: elasticsearch
```

However, i Have three questions related to my solution:
Can i make it static IP,so it does not change? can i assign more than port to more than deployment through the same external service ?
finally and its out of curiosity can i link a service to another service ? so for instance an external service request internal service and internal service request pod?
thanks.

Comment: **can i link a service to another service ? so for instance an external service request internal service and internal service request pod?**

`LoadBalancer` type Service that you're using behaves in the same manner. Client sends request on LB's IP (external) which in turn hits internal `Service`'s Cluster IP provided by k8s which in turn hits the selected pods

You can also do the same thing using a combination of `Service` of type `ClusterIP` (instead of `LoadBalancer`) and `Ingress` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) Resource.

Comment: **Can i make it static IP,so it does not change?**

You can provide IP to your `Service` by specifying `spec.clusterIP` field (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/cluster-ip-allocation/#why-do-you-need-to-reserve-service-cluster-ips). However, manually assigning IPs becomes on a large scale which why k8s manages them for us automatically.